# EmguCV- Capture screenshot from a video whenever the video gets updated

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

From a video, i want to capture images of all the updated frames .
The video is in windows media format (wmv), and what i am looking forward is to **capture all the images from it whenever the video updates the visuals in it**.

The video plays slowly , so i need to capture the screenshot of it whenever the frames updates or whenever the visuals in the video changes.

Using emgucv, I think we can add the frames like this.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> imgframe = video.QueryFrame();
image_array.Add(imgframe.Copy());
```

As i am a beginner, i need a helping hand.

Comment: kindly explain it in more details what you want ? what is your problem ? above mentions is not sufficient

Comment: what do you mean by "i want to capture images of all updated views from it" ?

Comment: @usmanlqbal Whenever the video updates,  i need to capture the image. Is it possible ...

Comment: What do means by update video. ? If you took single video file how would you update that. ? Kindly explain so that i will be able to guide you

Comment: Consider 3 pages in a website, first it is in `Home Page`. When you click `Next` Button, the page updates to a `New page`. Similarly, there are `Pages` in the video, starting with `Page 1` followed by `Page 2, Page 3`... From `Page 1`  initially, it gets changed to `Page 2 ` and thus the video is updated. Is it clear @usmanlqbal

Answer (score 1):

You need a Capture object and then process each and every frame of it, adding it to you array. To do so, you need to use Capture.ImageGrabbed event. Those are the very basics of using Emgu, so IMO you need to learn them yourself, or you will get stuck on each and every thing.
[If you're going to use EmguCV i strongly suggest to get use of their website. I made my whole engineering project using only their website. You can do it too :P](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Video_Files)